# nodejs cache issue with module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, module, export

I am a newbie in nodejs.

I have this Script: `book.js`

```
var page = 0;

exports.setPageCount = function (count) {
    page = count; 
}

exports.getPageCount = function(){
    return page;
}
```

Along with the follownig script: `scripts.js`

```
var bookA = require('./book');

var bookB = require('./book');

bookA.setPageCount(10);

bookB.setPageCount(20);

console.log("Book A Pages : " + bookA.getPageCount());

console.log("Book B Pages : " + bookB.getPageCount());
```

The Output I get:

```
Book A Pages : 20
Book B Pages : 20
```

So, I modified script:

```
module.exports = function(){
    var page = 0;

    setPageCount  : function(count){
        page = count;
    },

    getPageCount : function(){

        return page;
    }

}
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
Book A Pages : 10
Book B Pages : 20
```

But still getting the original outcome, does anyone have an idea where I made an error?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to go about this and your last attempt is almost a valid one -- modify your module like so:

```
module.exports = function() {
  var pages = 0;
  return {
    getPageCount: function() {
      return pages;
    },
    setPageCount: function(p) {
      pages = p;
    }
  }
}
```

and your usage like so:

```
var bookFactory = require('./book');
var bookA = bookFactory();
var bookB = bookFactory();
bookA.setPageCount(10);
bookB.setPageCount(20);
console.log("Book A Pages : " + bookA.getPageCount());
console.log("Book B Pages : " + bookB.getPageCount());
```

Comment: var bookA = bookFactory();
            ^
TypeError: bookFactory is not a function

Comment: You could also choose to return a `class` or `prototype` from your module and use the `new` keyword. Many ways to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: I edited my post to reflect changes to your module too -- read your second attempt too quickly and on retrospection, realised that it needed to change too. Apologies.

Comment: please run ur code, it is showing outout both zero  Book A Pages : 0
Book B Pages : 0
becuase getPageCount when call ,variable pages get initialize by zero at top

Comment: Thanks a lot @daf, you are champion